# How to store a number in parse with UITextField?

Tags: ios

How to store a number in parse with UITextField? I understand uitextfield is a strong but how do I convert it to an int or float to save to a parse database? Any help would be great!

Here is my code:

```
-(IBAction)addAccount:(id)sender {
  PFObject *Account = [PFObject          objectWithClassName:@"Account"];
 Account[@"startingBalance"] =          self.balance.text;
[Account saveInBackground];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store it as an `NSNumber`.  The best way to get an `NSNumber` from an `NSString` is via `NSNumberFormatter`.

```
NSString *balanceString = self.balance.text;

NSNumberFormatter *f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
NSNumber *balanceNumber = [f numberFromString:balanceString];

// use lower case for instance vars
PFObject *account = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Account"];
account[@"startingBalance"] = balanceNumber;
```